# Balance and proportions

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is a weird one because I've already solved the problem but I'm not quite happy in the process. Here is question:

We have a recipie for an orange juice cocktail of 130cc. In order to obtain the best cocktail on the earth you have to mix 7 parts of water with 3 parts of orange juice (uhmm not so juicy) but unfortanetly you have only a brick with a juice made 50% of water and 50% of orange juice. How much water you have to add to keep the ratio intact?

My thinking process was logical and not strictly mathematical. So if I have to keep the juyce to 3 parts, this will automatically add 3 parts of water that must be subtracted by the 7 part max we can add.

So we have to add 4 parts more to achieve the desired ration. How much water in cc we hate to add? First we have to find how many cc is a "part" and this will be

$$7x+3x = 130$$

so one part is 13cc. Then is straight forward:

$$ 13 * 4 = 52$$

52cc is our ansewer! The problem is that I have very hard time to put this stuff in mathematical terms and reduce my thinking process to a system of equations. . . Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the amount of pure water that has te be added with $x$.  The unknown $y$ is the volume of bricky orange juice you need.

The total amount of liquid is then $x+y$.  This has to be $130 cc$ so:
$$
x + y = 130 $$

The amount of water in the liquid is $x + \frac{1}{2} y$, because half of the content of the brick is pure water.  The ratio of water to orange juice has to be 7/10.  Hence:
$$
\frac{x + \frac{1}{2}y}{x + y} = \frac{7}{10}.
$$

We simplify this equation
$$
10 x + 5y = 7x +7y,
$$
and putting everything to the same side of the equation, we get
$$
3x - 2y = 0.
$$

Now you have a system of two linear equations with two unkown:
\begin{cases}
x + y = 130 \\ 3x - 2 y = 0
\end{cases}

Have fun solving this for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Hold on a sec! I realise this is not entirely what you want.  I shall edit!

Comment: Great! I was almost there but what I did was 1/2x + 1/2y = 1 and got stuck. . .

Answer (score 0):

Out of the $130$ cc of final product, we want $39$ cc of pure orange juice.  We can get that by using $\frac {39}{0.5}=78$ cc of the brick.  We also want $91$ cc of water.  We got $39$ cc of that from the brick, so we need to add $91-39=52$ cc of water.

Comment: Or *slightly* simpler:  You put in $78$ cc of "stuff", to have the juice you want, so you need $52$ cc of water to make $130$ cc total you want...